# Crontab doesn't backup postgre DB in docker, but if i run script by hand it work prorely

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, cron

I'm trying to set up automatic backup for postgre database. Postgre running in docker, so my script for backup is:

```
docker-compose exec postgres -U user database_name | gzip > "/var/server/my_service/data/backup-db/db_backup.sql.gz"
```

And its working fine, if I run it manually. I wrote the following job for the crontab (every 5 minutes just for testing):

```
*/5 * * * * cd /var/server/my_service && sh /var/server/my_service/data/backup/backup_script
```

This command also working great, if i run it manually it create valid DB backups that i can use.
But crontab just create empty archive, without any data. I just cant understand why.
My guess is that the output stream that catches the gzip is normally generated in manual mode, but completely empty when the crontab trying to run command

I thought there were problems with access rights and put the in the root crontab  but it didn't help

---

UPD:
so... problem in backup_script, error in logs says `the input device is not a TTY`

I tried google it and add -T, but it didn't help as well

Comment: Try redirecting to a log file as `backup_script >> file.log 2>&1` on crontab or check your system mail with `mail`. Crontab errors used to be there when crontab produces stdout or stderror message. https://devanswers.co/you-have-mail-how-to-read-mail-in-ubuntu/

Comment: @LMC updated the question, logs show `the input device is not a TTY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `/var/server/my_service/data/backup/backup_script` with the following:

Prefix the first 3 line in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile
cd /var/server/my_service

#
# rest of your script
#
```

Your `crontab` line should be ([At 04:44 on every day-of-month](https://crontab.guru/#44_4_*/1_*_*)):

```
44 4 */1 * * /var/server/my_service/data/backup/backup_script
```